# Static Resource blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Policy

Tags: visualforce-component, static-resources, cross-domain

I have a global Visualforce component in the package I am developing that uses the following Static Resource to load fonts:

```
<apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ImagesAndJavascriptZip, '/css/fontFamilies.css')}"/>
```

When this component is used in pages within the package, the fonts render correctly. However, when the component is used in a custom Visualforce Page outside of the package, the fonts do not render correctly and the following error is thrown in the Chrome console:

```
Font from origin 'https://zqci06.na3.visual.force.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://c.na3.visual.force.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have tried adding https://zqci06.na3.visual.force.com to the CORS Whitelist, but that still did not resolve the issue. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try with the namespace of the package being added

lets assume your namespace is zqci06

then the way to access it will be as follows

```
<apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.zqci06__ImagesAndJavascriptZip, '/css/fontFamilies.css')}"/>
```

Comment: It shouldn't be this issue because the component is developed inside the package

Comment: The issue happens when a page outside the package is referencing static resources in the package .So namespace could be one of the reasons .

Comment: How can I dynamically add the package namespace to the URLFOR command? I ask because my managed package can have different namespaces depending on whether it is a Beta package or a Released package.

Comment: First question is did this solved your problem ? Or do you still see CORS error

Comment: You can create a custom setting that's not protected and use post install script to populate namespace if your BETA and released packages are name spaced different

Comment: @SuryatejMukkamalla if this solution works for you, to add namespace dynamically, simply don't use apex:styleSheet. Use something like: `<link class="user" href="/resource/{!Namespace}__MainCss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>` . I haven't tried with zip files. But for normal css files it works for me.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, I have not yet tried your approach because I don't want to hardcode the namespace into the URL path, that is why I asked about how to dynamically add the namespace.

Comment: @LanceShi, I will try your approach and post back with the results

Comment: Hi, same problem for me... I have created a package with static resource. Lightning component works like a charm, but, for classic, we are getting CORS Policy error for customers those who don't make “Enable serving VF pages from Salesforce.com domain”. 

I have try both: 
`URLFOR($Resource.[pref]__[resource], '/[path]')`
`$Resource.[pref]__[resource], '/[path]'`

But same error again. If customer do “Enable serving VF pages from Salesforce.com domain”, sources are loaded successfully, but they don't want to change. Is there a way to get rid of this error? @MohithShrivastava

Comment: Can you put another question here ? The question you are asking seems bit different in it's own

Answer (score 0):

I have filed a ticket with Salesforce support and their response is that this is a known issue occurring with some customers using the Chrome browser. I am waiting to hear back about when they are planning to deploy the fix.

Comment: Did you try with hardcoded namespace to see if it fixes ?

Answer (score 0):

As this is an known issue for Salesforce, and we know that it might take years for them to make a deployment for the fix, I would suggest you to take a walkaround for this issue.

One simple way to do this is in your page outside the package, add this line of code:

```
<apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.YOURNAMESPACE__ImagesAndJavascriptZip, '/css/fontFamilies.css')}"/>
```

Assuming your resource is public, it should work fine for you.